# SQLAlchemy .execute() syntax for passing in variables

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to update column named dhl_team of my table players table for a specific row with ID 8476923 as an example. If I run:

```
db.execute("UPDATE players SET dhl_team = 10 WHERE id = 8476923");
```

It updates the table as I would expect.

What I would rather do is pass in the updated info from variables that I have set. For example

```
x = 1
k = 8476923
db.execute("UPDATE players SET dhl_team = 10 WHERE id = 8476923");
```

I fell like it should be something like:

```
x = 1
k = 8476923
db.execute("UPDATE players SET dhl_team = :x", {"x": x}) WHERE id = 8476923");
```

## But this returns an error;

```
db.execute("UPDATE players SET dhl_team = :x", {"x": x}) WHERE id = 8476923");
                                                                 ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can someone tell me how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass two arguments to the `.execute` method:

1. The *entire* SQL statement text, including parameter placeholders.
2. A `dict` containing the parameter names and their values.

So in your case you would be looking at

```python
import sqlalchemy as sa

# ...

db = sa.create_engine(connection_uri)
sql = sa.text("UPDATE players SET dhl_team = :x WHERE id = 8476923")
params = {"x": 1}
with db.begin() as cnxn:
    cnxn.execute(sql, params)
print("Update completed.")
```

Comment: Thank-you, that was helpful. I will post the code that used that also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I used that also worked.

x = 1

k = 8476923

db.execute("UPDATE players SET dhl_team = :x WHERE id = :k",  {"x": x, "k": k});